# Element a not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Tags: html, css

Here is the error:

```
<nav role="navigation">
<div id="menuToggle">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <ul id="menu">
            <a href="artists.html">
                <li id="Artists">Artists</li>
            </a>
            <a href="music.html">
                <li id="Music">Music</li>
            </a>
            <a href="shop.html">
                <li id="Shop">Shop</li>
            </a>
            <a href="contact.html">
                <li id="Contact">Contact</li>
            </a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I know that a child of ul can only be li, but I don't know how to li around the a tags. How can I change it, so that it looks the same?

Comment: a belongs inside li. only li is allowed a direct child of ul.

Comment: Just read [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct structure is:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="">text</a></li>
</ul>
```

Read this [article](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li).

In your case, it will be like this:

```html
<nav role="navigation">
<div id="menuToggle">
    <input type="checkbox"/>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <ul id="menu">
            <li id="Artists"><a href="artists.html">Artists</a></li>
            <li id="Music"><a href="music.html">Music</a></li>
            <li id="Shop"><a href="shop.html">Shop</a></li>            
            <li id="Contact"><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put anchor tag inside li.

e.g `<li><a href="whatever">your stuff</a></li>`